# Page Layouts: Two users with same profile have different layouts?

Tags: administration, profile, page-layout, user-management, roles

I have two users that have different roles but the same profile.

I cleaned up some page layouts for our lead and contact objects and am testing them with a particular set of users. No issues with the people I know are testing.

However, someone from another department said they said their page layouts changed too. I compared her profile to someone else in her department, and they matched. I verified one has the updated layout, and the other doesn't.

I went to check Page Layout Assignments for both objects and confirmed their profiles should have the default layout.

I verified their profiles were the same in Setup --> Users

I am not a certified Salesforce admin by any means. I can move my way around objects and some basic formulas. We're a small company (about 30 people in total) and don't have a Salesforce admin.

How can this have happened?

Where should I look to find more information?

How can I resolve this?

I'm in Salesforce Enterprise Edition (Classic)

Comment: Is it possible that they actually are on the same layout but the users don't have access to the same fields so the page layouts look different? Do the permissions sets assigned to your users match?

Comment: We're pretty open about who has access to what fields, and on the old layouts (that I  cloned from), they did not have this issue. I created a section and moved some standard and custom fields to it, and it's pretty obvious the layout differs from our old one. I will double check the permission sets.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing the two things below, I'd really confirm that they're experiencing different layouts *at the same time* after a refresh/hard refresh. They can do this in chrome by clicking on F12 and right clicking on the refresh icon and selecting "empty cache and hard reload". *Note: this will erase any pinned list views they have saved.*

It's possible they're experiencing the same change at different times or maybe someone has edited the layout at different times.

---

Otherwise, **Field permissions** would control whether they actually see a field on a layout. Even though their profiles are identical (and they have identical layouts), a field's visibility may be set to false at the profile level and set to true through a ***permission set.***

For here, I'd confirm the two users have the same permission sets. If they do not, look at what fields on the object in question the permission set is setting.

Setup --> Permission Sets --> Click on permission set --> Object Settings --> Click on object

Comment: There's a whole host of other factors in lightning such as which app the user is viewing the page from as well. The OP mentioned specifically they are in classic.

Comment: Definitely missed that comment at the end. Removed lightning info as it wasn't applicable and not complete anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if its classic then i bet they have different permission sets ... FLS is set at profile , so if they have same profile the only other option to be seeing different fields on page  ( i assume this is not layout issue ) has to be perm set .